How to get a log from Proton when not running in Steam
The Proton README says that setting the environment variable PROTON_LOG=1 will create files at ~/steam-*.log with debug information. However, when running Proton without the Steam client (for example, by installing the AUR package), no log file is created.

You have to set the SteamGameId environment variable in addition to PROTON_LOG. For example:
export SteamGameId=not-steam
export STEAM_COMPAT_CLIENT_INSTALL_PATH=$HOME/.local/share/Steam
export STEAM_COMPAT_DATA_PATH=$STEAM_COMPAT_CLIENT_INSTALL_PATH/steamapps/compatdata/$SteamGameId
export PROTON_LOG=1
mkdir -p $STEAM_COMPAT_DATA_PATH
/usr/share/steam/compatibilitytools.d/proton/proton run winecfg

Presto, now you have ~/steam-not-steam.log.
